# Using pipe to pass data between two processes continuously

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe, fork

I'm trying to make two child process to communicate with each other via a pipe.

One child is supposed to keep reading from stdin, passing what it read to the pipe, while the other child is supposed to read from the pipe and print that to stdout.

I manage to get it to work, but only once, in the second iteration after reading a number, I get: `write failed: Bad file descriptor`.

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong...

```
#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1
int main(){

    int pipe_descs[2];
    int retval = pipe(pipe_descs);
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){   //son that reads from stdin and writes to pipe 
        close(pipe_descs[READ]);
        int x;
        while(1){
            open(pipe_descs[WRITE]);
            scanf("%d", &x);
            if(write(pipe_descs[WRITE], &x, sizeof(int)) != sizeof(int)){
                perror("write failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            close(pipe_descs[WRITE]);
        }
        perror("");
    }
    else if(pid > 0){   //parent

        int pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){   //son that reads from pipe and write to stdout 
            int pipestat;
            int readNum;
            close(pipe_descs[WRITE]);
            while((pipestat = read(pipe_descs[READ], &readNum, sizeof(int))) > 0){

                printf("read: %d \n", readNum);
                //close(pipe_descs[READ]);
                //open(pipe_descs[READ]);
            }
            if (pipestat==-1) {
                perror("");
                fprintf(stderr, "error to pipe... exiting\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    int status;
    int i = 2;
    while (i > 0){
        wait(&status);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you think `open(pipe_descs[WRITE]);` will do ? Second, why closing it in the loop ? Non-sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem #1

If you're going to close the writer (`close(pipe_descs[WRITE]);`), you can't keep using it! Either remove that statement, or exit the loop after closing the pipe.

### Problem #2

`open(pipe_descs[WRITE])` makes no sense! Get rid of that.

### Problem #3

*[If your system complies with POSIX.1-2001, and if the amount you are writing is smaller than `PIPE_BUF`, then you can ignore this section.]*

`write(..., sizeof(int)) != sizeof(int)` doesn't (necessarily) indicate an error condition. If no error occurred, then `write` didn't set `errno` to something meaningful, so the error message you obtained is meaningless.

Since it's not an error for `write` to write less than the requested amount, it needs to be called in the a loop. Replace

```
        if(write(pipe_descs[WRITE], &x, sizeof(int)) != sizeof(int)){
            perror("write failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

with

```
        my_write(pipe_descs[WRITE], &x, sizeof(x));
```

and add

```
void my_write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t bytes_to_write) {
    while (bytes_to_write > 0) {
        ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd, buf, bytes_to_write);
        if (bytes_written == -1) {
            perror("write failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        buf            += bytes_written;
        bytes_to_write -= bytes_written;
    }
}
```

---

Similar, it's not an error for `read` to return less than the requested amount. As such, it also needs to be called in the a loop. Replace

```
        while((pipestat = read(pipe_descs[READ], &readNum, sizeof(int))) > 0){

            printf("read: %d \n", readNum);
            //close(pipe_descs[READ]);
            //open(pipe_descs[READ]);
        }
        if (pipestat==-1) {
            perror("");
            fprintf(stderr, "error to pipe... exiting\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

with

```
        while (my_read(pipe_descs[READ], &readNum, sizeof(readNum))) {
            printf("read: %d \n", readNum);
        }
```

and add

```
int my_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t bytes_to_read) {
    int has_read = 0;
    while (bytes_to_read > 0) {
        ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, buf, bytes_to_read);
        if (bytes_read == -1) {
            perror("read failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (bytes_read == 0) {
             if (has_read) {
                 fprintf(stderr, "read failed: Premature EOF");
                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             }

             return 0;
        }

        has_read = 1;

        buf           += bytes_read;
        bytes_to_read -= bytes_read;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It's a minimal example, but in my actual code I write structs, so not writing or reading the whole struct must be an error no?

Comment: @kuhaku, No, `write` not writing the entire struct doesn't necessarily indicate an error. Not writing the entire struct would be a coding error you on your part, but I showed you how to call `write` repeatedly to ensure the entire structure gets written.

Comment: In a pipe, write is atomic (provided the length is less than PIPE_BUF which should be at least 512), so writing an int should return the size of it, if not, something's wrong happened.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès, That's irrelevant for two reasons. 1) The posted program, and more importantly the actual program giving the errors, send far more than just an int, so it's possible that the pipe did fill up. 2) You still have to read until `write` returns `-1` to get the error message.

Comment: When a pipe is full, then the write will block, that's the pipe semantic in blocking mode.

Comment: Problem is that OP closes the descriptor in the loop, this is why it works only once. Simple.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès, We're not talking about when it's full, we're talking about when it becomes full mid-write.

Comment: Definitely a problem too! Adding to answer.

Comment: Please read about pipe I/Os semantic. write is guaranteed to be atomic!

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès, I believe I found that to which you are referring. On POSIX.1-2001 systems, writes are atomic if they're small enough. I have no idea if he's using a POSIX.1-2001 system or how big the structure he is writing is, so I can't assume it's atomic. BUT, I will add this information to the answer.